# Multiple many to many relationship database design

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Currently i have a booking system using MySQL database with some main tables like Campaigns, Staffs, Customers and Appointments.
Some basic relationships like:

```
+ One to Many : Appointments - Staffs, Appointments - Campaigns and Appointments - Customer.
+ Many to Many: Campaigns - Staffs, Campaigns - Customers.
```

However, i have a function that need to managed the time_available for each staff in each campaign and display it in each day until the end of the campaign. It also need to determined which time slot is booked and which is free.

Let say it is guaranteed that in no campaign will staff have duplicate time_available.

The db tables i have right now is something like this

- Service

  - name
  - start_time
  - end_time
  - is_end
- Customer

  - name
  - email
- Staff

  - name
  - email
- Appointment

  - customer
  - staff
  - campaign
  - start_time
  - end_time

Should i add another table like TimeAvailable or something to store the data? Then which kind of relationship will it need?

And do i need to store it as a single data for every day until the end of the campaign?

Comment: yes,  it is end - start. I made a mistake putting it there.

Comment: Sorry, i was at work and i'm intent to fix it when i get home since it does not have any effect on the question.

Comment: Is the Campaigns related to Staffs & Customers through Appointments ?

Comment: Is Service is actually Campaign ?